# Microsoft IRM and ClientAccessServerEnabled Option

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-web-app, activesync

I'm looking for some additional insight on Microsoft IRM and the ClientAccessServerEnabled option, and what enabling or disabling does and any potential ramifications.

About half of the tutorials tell you to disable this and the other half tell you to enable it. It sounds like if I enable this, which is the default value according to the most current documentation, I might need to configure AD RMS too.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/encryption-and-certificates/set-irmconfiguration?view=exchange-ps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, An AD RMS cluster must be installed in the Active Directory forest. And Enabling Information Rights Management (IRM) on Client Access servers will enable the following features:

Microsoft Office Outlook Web App

IRM in Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync